# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

El problema es al intentar guardar el text de un label en Tk, ya que al intentar extraerlo despues de cerrar la ventana, este se elimina por el mainloop pero no veo manera de guardar esta variable previamente o a  "tiempo real"

````py
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import (WD_BUILTIN_STYLE, WD_STYLE, WD_STYLE_TYPE)
from docx.enum.text import (WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT, WD_COLOR, WD_LINE_SPACING)
from docx.shared import Emu, Pt, Cm, RGBColor
from tkinter import*

black = RGBColor(0,0,0)

#COMANDOS
def seleccionar():
   cadena= ""
   if (alimentos.get()):
       cadena+= "Alimentos"
   if (relacion.get()):
       if cadena=="":
           cadena+= "Relacion Directa y Regular"
       else:
           cadena+=", Relacion Directa y Regular"
   if (cuidado.get()):
       if cadena=="":
           cadena+= "Cuidado Personal"
       else:
           cadena+=", Cuidado Personal"
   Materia4.config(text=cadena)
def mediador1():
   rmediador.config(text=strmediador1)
   Rut1.config(text="6.822.863-8")
def mediador2():
   rmediador.config(text=strmediador2)
   Rut1.config(text="11.617.128-7")
def solicitantef(x):
   Solicitante2.config(text=str(Solicitante1.get()))
def solicita():
   Solicitante1.bind("<Return>",solicitantef)
def rut1(x):
   RUTSolicitante2.config(text=str(RUTSolicitante1.get()))
def rutt():
   RUTSolicitante1.bind("<Return>",rut1)
def solicitadof(x):
   Solicitado2.config(text=str(Solicitado1.get()))
def solicitad():
   Solicitado1.bind("<Return>",solicitadof)
def rut2(x):
   RUTSolicitado2.config(text=str(RUTSolicitado1.get()))
def ruttt():
   RUTSolicitado1.bind("<Return>",rut2)
   
#VENTANA INTERACTIVA  
v=Tk(); f0=Frame(v);f1=Frame(v);f2=Frame(v);f3=Frame(v);f4=Frame(v);f5=Frame(v);f6=Frame(v);f7=Frame(v);f8=Frame(v);f9=Frame(v)
Titulo=Label(f0,text="Mediabot familiar version 1.0", width=60).pack()

#1.-Materia
alimentos=IntVar() #1 si, 0 no
relacion=IntVar() #1 si, 0 no
cuidado=IntVar() #1 si, 0 no
Materia0=Label(f3,text="Materia:",width=30,anchor=CENTER)
Materia1=Checkbutton(f3, text="Alimentos",variable=alimentos,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=seleccionar,width=30)
Materia2=Checkbutton(f3, text="Relacion Directa y Regular",variable=relacion,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=seleccionar,width=30)
Materia3=Checkbutton(f3, text="Cuidado Personal",variable=cuidado,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=seleccionar,width=30)
Materia4=Label(f3,width=60)

#2.-Mediador
Mediador0=Label(f4, text= "Mediador:", width=30,anchor=NW)
strmediador1=str("Patricia Chandia Bustamante");Mediador1=Button(f4,text=strmediador1, width=45,command=mediador1)
strmediador2=str("Patricia Rojas Chandia");Mediador2=Button(f4,text=strmediador2, width=45,command=mediador2)
rmediador=Label(f4,text="",width=60)

#3.-Rut Mediador
Rut05=StringVar()
Rut0=Label(f5,text="Rut:", width=30,anchor=CENTER)
Rut05=Label(f5,text="", width=90)
Rut1=Label(f5,text="", width= 60)

#4.-Parte 1 (Solicitante)
Solicitante0=Label(f6, text="Nombre Solicitante:", width=40,anchor=NW)
Solicitante1=Entry(f6,text="ola", width=90)
Solicitante2=Label(f6,text=" ", width=60)
solicita()

#5.-RUT Parte 1 (Solicitante)
RUTSolicitante0=Label(f7, text="RUT Solicitante:", width=40,anchor=NW)
RUTSolicitante1=Entry(f7, width=90)
RUTSolicitante2=Label(f7,text="", width=60)
rutt()

#6.-Parte 2 (Solicitado)
Solicitado0=Label(f8, text="Nombre Solicitado:", width=40,anchor=NW)
Solicitado1=Entry(f8, width=90)
Solicitado2=Label(f8,text=" ", width=60)
solicitad()

#7.-RUT Parte 2 (Solicitado)
RUTSolicitado0=Label(f9, text="RUT Solicitado:", width=40,anchor=NW)
RUTSolicitado1=Entry(f9, width=90)
RUTSolicitado2=Label(f9,text=" ", width=60)
ruttt()

#pack
Label(f1, text="", width=60).pack()
Label(f2, text="", width=60).pack()
Materia0.pack(side=LEFT);Materia1.pack(side=LEFT);Materia2.pack(side=LEFT);Materia3.pack(side=LEFT);Materia4.pack(side=LEFT)
Mediador0.pack(side=LEFT);Mediador1.pack(side=LEFT);Mediador2.pack(side=LEFT);rmediador.pack(side=LEFT)
Rut0.pack(side=LEFT),Rut05.pack(side=LEFT);Rut1.pack(side=LEFT)
Solicitante0.pack(side=LEFT);Solicitante1.pack(side=LEFT);Solicitante2.pack(side=LEFT)
RUTSolicitante0.pack(side=LEFT);RUTSolicitante1.pack(side=LEFT);RUTSolicitante2.pack(side=LEFT)
Solicitado0.pack(side=LEFT);Solicitado1.pack(side=LEFT);Solicitado2.pack(side=LEFT)
RUTSolicitado0.pack(side=LEFT);RUTSolicitado1.pack(side=LEFT);RUTSolicitado2.pack(side=LEFT)
f0.pack(),f1.pack(),f2.pack(),f3.pack(),f4.pack(),f5.pack(),f6.pack(),f7.pack(),f8.pack(),f9.pack()
v.mainloop()```
Se que tiene que ver con que se elimina el dato al cerrar el mainloop, pero no encuentro una solucion optima, si alguien me puede ayudar
````

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que redefinir lo que sucede cuando se cierra la ventana. Un ejemplo es el siguiente:

```py
from tkinter import *

def save_label_text():
    store['label-text'] = label.cget('text')
    root.destroy()


store = dict()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('320x240')

label = Label(root, text='Texto del Label')
label.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)


root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', save_label_text)
root.mainloop()

label_text_after_close = store['label-text']
print(label_text_after_close)
```

En el ejemplo, he creado una ventana llamada `root` que contiene una etiqueta llamada `label`. Lo importante aquí es lo siguiente:

```py
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', save_label_text)
```

De esta manera, cuando el usuario presione **X** para cerrar la ventana, se ejecutará la función `save_label_text`:

```py
def save_label_text():
    store['label-text'] = label.cget('text')
    root.destroy()
```

En esta función almacenamos el texto del `label` antes de ejecutar `root.destroy()`, que cierra la ventana.

`store` es un diccionario que he creado fuera de la función para que sea *globalmente accesible*. Puedes utilizar cualquier variable global para almacenar el texto (yo he utilizado un diccionario porque no me gusta utilizar  `global` dentro de las funciones, y además de esta manera puedes almacenar muchos datos sin tener que crear demasiadas variables globales).

Al cerrarse la ventana se ejecuta la siguiente línea después de `root.mainloop()`. Obtienes el *texto de la etiqueta* accediendo al valor almacenado en `store`:

```py
label_text_after_close = store['label-text']
print(label_text_after_close)
```

Un saludo!